# Magento PWA access denied

Tags: php, ubuntu, magento, magento2

I am trying to install magneto on my windows 10 using ubuntu terminal but I got that error which I don't know what to do to solve it ,I tried to find env.php file but it don't exist and I have read a lot but I didn't find a solution ,I am new to this so if you can tell me where to find the folder I should edit and what data to edit

I run this in the root of my project

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/mage0 --db-host=localhost --db-name=mahesh_mage0 --db-user=root --db-password=*** --admin-firstname=Mohamed --admin-lastname=Nageh --admin-email=test@mohamed.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --backend-frontname=admin_magento --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=Asia/Tbilisi --cleanup-database --use-rewrites=1
```

The error I got

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Open & Edit /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf, depending on your distro.
   2 . Add skip-grant-tables under [mysqld]
2. Restart Mysql
3. You should be able to login to mysql now using the below command mysql -u root -p
4. Run mysql> flush privileges;
5. Set new password by ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
6. Go back to /etc/my.cnf and remove/comment skip-grant-tables
7. Restart Mysql
8. Now you will be able to login with the new password mysql -u root -p

Then use the user credentials and the password you just set to run the setup command again

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: When I try to restart Mysql I got this error

Comment: No directory, logging in with HOME=/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//.cache’: Permission denied
-su: 19: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: Directory nonexistent

Comment: I use this command => sudo service mysql restart

Comment: If you are using windows operating system you cannot use the above command to restart Mysql. To restart you can follow the instructions in this article: https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-start-stop-restart-mysql-server.html